# How to only show all articles that contains a particular value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Currently using Laravel 8, I have to show on a page all articles but only the ones that contain a specific row value in my Database. For instance, in this one, I have a column in the desired table that is called "is_reserved" as TinyInt acting as a True or false (1-0).

I have searched absolutely everywhere and I cannot understand nor find the right syntax for filtering and show only articles that aren't reserved (is_reserved = 0).

In my blade view file, I have a @foreach loop that fetches my item from my controller, like the following below. Which works by the way, just not the way I intend it to be. I'm out of ideas.

**TL:DR:** I just want to be able to show all items from my database but only the ones with a specific row value.

```html
<section class="row justify-content-evenly mt-5 mx-sm-3">
    @foreach ($donations as $donation)
    <article class="box col-md-5 col-sm-12 row p-3 mt-md-3 mt-sm-5 d-flex justify-content-around">
        <img src="{{ $donation->image }}" alt="image" class="col" style="border-radius: 100%;">
        <div class="col">
            <p style="text-align: justify;">{{ Str::limit($donation->description, 80) }}</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-column text-left" style="width: auto; height: 100px;">
                <h5>Location: Quebec</h5>
                <p>Meteo: Cold</p>
                <div class="row justify-content-between">

                    <button class="col-5 btn yellowBtn">reserve</button>
                    <a class="col-5 btn greenBtn" href="{{route('view-item', $donation->id)}}">View</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: "*I have searched absolutely everywhere and I cannot understand nor find the right syntax [...]*" - It's actually quite easy to find in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses or https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#building-queries... Sidenote, you don't run queries in your view, but rather your Controller.

Comment: simply define a key as an integer in casting your model and then set where the condition  ->where('is_reserved', 1)  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the logic to the controller / service before looping through them, then send the necessary rows to your blade (probably with a `$is_reserved` boolean in the array/object)

Keep in mind that if you're diving into logic in the blade / template file itself, it's best to move it back a step and just provide the template the simplest data you can.

Taking your question as an example, **before** sending the rows to the template, and just show the ones that match your need.

e.g.

```
$rows = DB::table('your_table')->where('is_reserved', '1')->get();
return $rows; //or extend your template here
```

Otherwise, you can ad an `@if` condition right to your template, and render only if ceratin condition is met

Comment: I have tried doing the if condition right after my @foreach line, and it works now. Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: @Antony_Web glad I could help :) mark as "Selected answer" if it did help you towards your solution.